# How to Calculate and Publish Arrays in SwiftUI

Tags: arrays, swiftui

In SwiftUI, if I declare an array variable with the property wrapper `@Published`, and then calculate each element of that array within a `for()` loop, will the variable be published each time I compute a new element?  If so, is there a way to tell the compiler to not publish the variable until every element is computed?

I have an app that computes a spectrum for each successive frame of audio data.  The app then publishes that `spectrum[]` to several Views that render fancy graphics.  I want each View to re-draw only once for each successive frame of audio data - not once for each computed element of the `spectrum[]` array.

Here's some simplified code to illustrate the problem:

```
class ArrayGenerator: ObservableObject {
    @Published var spectrum = [Float](repeating: 0.0, count: 1000) 

    DispatchQueue.main.async { [self] in
        for bin in 0 ..< 1000 {
            spectrum[bin] = (userGain + userSlope * Float(bin)) * amplitudes[bin]
        }
    }
}
```

Since this code changes the variable 1,000 times, I believe it publishes it 1,000 times.  But I want it to be published only once - when the `for()` loop is completed.  How can I accomplish this?

Comment: " I believe it publishes it 1,000 times" -- have you tested to make sure this is actually the case? Doesn't seem likely.

Comment: Have I tested it?  No. I am just going by the SwiftUI documentation which states that @published variables are published whenever they are modified.  I'm hoping someone knowledgeable in how SwiftUI handles arrays can explain what's happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your assumption that it will publish 1000 changes/renders is incorrect. All of those iterations of the `for` loop will be done in *one* iteration of the  main run loop. Take this simple example:

```
class ArrayGenerator: ObservableObject {
    @Published var spectrum = [Float](repeating: 0.0, count: 1000)

    func run() {
        DispatchQueue.main.async { [self] in
            for bin in 0 ..< 1000 {
                spectrum[bin] = Float(bin)
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @StateObject private var generator = ArrayGenerator()
    
    var body: some View {
        let _ = print("Rendering...")
        Text(generator.spectrum.map { String($0) }.joined())
            .onAppear {
                generator.run()
            }
    }
}
```

Which prints:

```
Rendering...
Rendering...
```

It renders once for the first appearance, then the `onAppear` runs, and then an additional render after the loop is done.

So, your code already does what you expect.

Comment: Thank you, jnpdx.  I am convinced that you are right, but I still don't understand why you are right.  Your observation that "All of those iterations of the for loop will be done in one iteration of the main run loop" is true.  But it does not obviate the fact that my code modifies the @Published array 1,000 times, and Apple's SwiftUI documentation states clearly that the variable is published whenever it is modified.  I have not seen any documentation that makes an exception if all those modifications are wrapped inside a control-flow statement.

Comment: It's not about being wrapped in a control flow statement -- it's how run loops work in general. If you're on the main thread (which you are because of `DispatchQueue.main.async`), the main thread doesn't interrupt itself in the middle of a function like this to go run other code (like re-rendering the view) and then return to what it was currently executing, again, on the same thread. If threads worked like this we'd have quite a bit of trouble rationalizing what happens in what order in a program.

Comment: So, yes, it *looks like* you modify it 1000 times (although the compiler very well may optimize that out as well) but this happens all within one pass of the run loop, as I mentioned in my answer. The documentation isn't wrong and this isn't an "exception" -- it just doesn't go into specific detail about how threads/runloops work.

Comment: Thank you, jnpdx.  Your explanation is excellent.  But if leads to the question that I am REALLY asking:  My actual app is much more complicated than the simplified example above.  There are several arrays computed and published - and all of them are CPU-intensive.  If I do all the computation on the main thread, then my entire app becomes single-threaded and would run extremely slowly.  Is there a way to do the computation of the arrays on background threads - and only use the main thread to publish the final arrays when they are finished?

Comment: Yes. You can do exactly what you are describing. Do the calculations on a separate thread, then do one assignment of the result to the `@Published` variable -- `DispatchQueue.main.async { spectrum = theResultOfMyExpensiveCalculation }`

Comment: jnpdx, you are being extremely helpful.  But all of my attempts to do this result in the Thread Sanitizer generating memory access race conditions.  Could I ask you to generate a new answer showing how to let the compiler do the computations on any threads it wants, and then do only the publishing of the results on the main thread.  My experience is that, if I declare a variable to be @Published and then attempt to modify it (anywhere other than in DispatchQueue.main.async), I get a build error saying that I can't publish a variable outside of the main thread.

Comment: "But all of my attempts to do this result in the Thread Sanitizer generating memory access race conditions." Perhaps you should edit your question to include such an attempt. I've already given the example in my previous comment about how to set the `@Published` variable once, so I'm not sure what more to do without an example of what's going wrong.

Comment: Are you suggesting that I declare two variable arrays - with only one of them marked as @Published?  I would do all of the computation using the non-published one and then finally copy it to the array to be published.

Comment: No, I'm not. I'm suggesting you do your work, then set it to the `@Published` value. `let result = //do expensive work` and then `DispatchQueue.main.async { spectrum = result }`. If you need a copy of the array to do work in to create published, make a copy first `var workingCopy = spectrum; result = doWork; DispatchQueue.main.async { spectrum = result }`

Comment: Your last comment is exactly the same as my suggestion in the provious comment.  I should do all of the computation on the non-published array variable result[], and then copy it to the published variable spectrum[].  Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Ah, I assumed incorrectly that your comment meant declare two *properties* with only one being `@Published`. Yes, you should do all of the work on a local copy and set it *once* to the `@Published` array (see my examples above).

Answer (score 0):

Your assumption that it will publish 1000 changes is correct. objectWillChange is sent in the willSet and although SwiftUI coalesces these notifications into one render it is still something you would want to avoid. The way to fix that is to simply do your work on a copy of the array and then set the published property with the new version of the array once.